# If you take any natural number greater than three, take the square root and round it off ...

Tags: real-analysis, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> If you take any natural number greater than three, take the square
>   root and round it off, from the result you take the square root and
>   round it off again, and so on. Show that ,at some point, this process
>   leads to $2$ or $3$

I tried finding patterns in different examples, but I can't see any consistency:

$\lfloor(\sqrt{1234})\rfloor=35 ⇒ \lfloor\sqrt{35}\rfloor=5 ⇒ \lfloor\sqrt{5}\rfloor=2$

$\lfloor\sqrt{53123}\rfloor=230 ⇒ \lfloor \sqrt{230}\rfloor=15 ⇒ \lfloor\sqrt{15}\rfloor=3$

...

I also tried proving it by Induction, but I don't know that I even have to show..

Comment: Well:  If at any stage you have an integer $>3$ then the square root of that integer is $≥2$ so rounding it can not get you below $2$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Forget the floor for a bit and just think about what happens when you take repeated roots of $x$.  What does the exponent do?

Comment: the exponent becomes smaller and smaller....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $k$ is that natural number define $a_1=k$ and $a_{n+1}=\lfloor\sqrt{a_n}\rfloor$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$$
Also, $a_n$ is integer for every $n$. Then, the sequence is eventually constant.

Let $r$ be the least natural number such that $a_r=1$ (well-ordered property for that). Then $a_{r-1}$ is $2$ or $3$.